# Thermal Printer print barcode but print the bytes instead of the number

Tags: android, thermal-printer

I try to print a barcode in a Thermal printer but the printer print a different number, I need to print the barcode number that I defined.

Current Behavior 
My number is :    "12345678"
An the barcode printer is : https://snag.gy/VNxQs3.jpg
4950515253545556

Expected Behavior
My number is :    "12345678"
An the barcode printer is : https://snag.gy/OVlebj.jpg
12345678

```
   @Override
public void run()
{
    try {
        if(usbInterface != null && connection != null && mEndPoint != null) {
            if(connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true)) {

                printBarcode(connection,usbInterface);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("ClaimInterface is false, print again.");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Ocurrio un problema con la conexión...");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}

private void printBarcode(UsbDeviceConnection connection, UsbInterface interfaceUsb) {
String uuid  = "12345678";
byte[] uuidBytes = uuid.getBytes();
byte[] formats  = {(byte) 0x1d, (byte) 0x6b, (byte) 0x49, (byte)uuidBytes.length};

byte[] bytes    = new byte[formats.length + uuidBytes.length];


System.arraycopy(formats, 0, bytes, 0, formats.length );
System.arraycopy(uuidBytes, 0, bytes, formats.length, uuidBytes.length);

connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, bytes, bytes.length, TIMEOUT_COMMAND_PRINTER); }
```

In the documentation of the Command POS printer I found this:
  1D 6B m d1…dk 00 Print bar code
  or 1D 6B m n d1…dn
  It's the same command that I use

In the debug I can see that the number that is printer is the same to uuidBytes.getBytes like 
[49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

I'm using this printer :
https://support.hp.com/mx-es/drivers/selfservice/hp-dual-serial-usb-thermal-receipt-printer/4169725/model/4169726?sku=BM476AA

Comment: Don't forget to horizontally flip bits if the Printer protocol uses a different "bit numbering" (big vs little endian) than yours.

Comment: I already try to horizontally flip bits but now the barcode is not print, the printer only print 1K12345678 (plain text)

Comment: Did you use PrintWriter to print?

Comment: No, I only use   bulkTransfer method, mi printer is connected by USB and only send the bytes: connection.bulkTransfer(mEndPoint, bytes, bytes.length, 0);

Comment: If I sent to print plain text using this method, prints correctly, the problem is with the barcode

Comment: The problem was resolved, was a problem with the specification, I found the answer in the data sheet of Command POS. Thanks :) https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/Driver%20board.pdf I need an EAN13 and I was putting a code 128.